# Remove specific part of a file depending on another file in bash

Tags: awk, fasta

I'm looking for a bash command in order to remove part of the texte if the texte after `">"` is present in the `file1` and `file2`.

Here is an exemple

```
File1:

CUI02270
CUI02272
CUI02271
CUI02290
CUI02289
CUI022799


File2:

>CUI02270 |hypothetical protein pCPXV0248[Cowpox virus]
MGTVFVPYLLVKLALRVLVISNGYCHVPLKYIVLMIAHRVLLSSIVESTTLDIPDLRSTM
ELILLTASRLKFNLYRPNL
>CUI02271 |CPXV043 protein[Cowpox virus]
MLAFCYSLPNVGDVLKGKVYENGYALYIDLFDYPHSEAILAESVQMHMNRYFKYRDKLVG
KTVKVKVIRVDYTKGYIDVNYKRMCKHQ
>CUI02272 |hypothetical protein pCPXV0245[Cowpox virus]
MFTHPFVIDIYISFCIINSNHFNFYSFPYQFIPIFKISIHMHLNTLCQDSFRVRIVKKIN
V
>CUI02273 |CPXV044 protein[Cowpox virus]
MNPDNTIAVITETIPIGMQFDKVYLSTFNVWREILSNTTKTLDISSFYWSLLDEVGTNFG
TTILNEIVQLPKRGVRVRVAVNKSNKPLKDVETLQMAGVEVRYIDITNILGGVLHTKFWI
SDNTHIYLGSANMDWRSLTQVKELGIAIFNNRNLAADLTQIFEVYWYLGVNNLPYNWKNF
YPAYYNTDHPLSMNVSGVPHSVFIASAPQQLCTMERTNDLTALLSCIGNASKFVYVSVMN
FIPIIYSKAGNILFWPYIEDELRRTAIDRKVSVKLLISCWQRSSFIMRNFLRSIAMLKSK
NIDIEVKLFIVPDTDPPIPYSRVNHAKYMVTDKTAYIGTSNWTGNYFTDTCGTSINITPD
DGLGLRQQLEDIFMRDWNSKYSYELYDTSPTKRCRLLKNMKQCTNDIYSDEIQPEKEIPE
YSLE
>CUI02274 |CPXV045 protein[Cowpox virus]
MSANCMFNLDNDYIYCKYWKPITYPKALVFISHGAGEHSGRYDELAENISSLGILVFSHD
HIGHGRSNGEKMMIDDFGTYVRDVVQHVVTIKSTYPGVPVFLLGHSMGATISILAAYENP
NLFTAMILMSPLVNAEAVPRLNLLAAKLMGAITPNAPVGKLCPESVSRDMDEVYKYQYDP
LVNHEKIKAGFASQVLKATNKVRKIIPKINTPSLILQGTNNEISDVSGAYYFMQHANCNR
EIKIYEGAKHHLHKETDEVKKSVMKEIETWIFNRVK
>CUI022799 |CPXV046 protein[Cowpox virus]
MATKSDYEDAVFYFVDDDEICSRDSIIDLIDEYITWRNHVIVFNKDITSCGRLYKELMKF
DDAAIRYYGIDKINEIVEAMSEGDHYINLTEVHDQESLFATIGICAKITEHWGYKKISES
RFQSLGNITDLMTDDNINILILFLEKKLN
>CUI02276 |hypothetical protein pCPXV0240[Cowpox virus]
MDFCKIDVVVSFAHSLDNLINFINTIVPYSSIIELHQFLVESSTTGNIFVKHYNMISPRD
IFIY
```

than I should have a new `file3` such as :

```
>CUI02273 |CPXV044 protein[Cowpox virus]
MNPDNTIAVITETIPIGMQFDKVYLSTFNVWREILSNTTKTLDISSFYWSLLDEVGTNFG
TTILNEIVQLPKRGVRVRVAVNKSNKPLKDVETLQMAGVEVRYIDITNILGGVLHTKFWI
SDNTHIYLGSANMDWRSLTQVKELGIAIFNNRNLAADLTQIFEVYWYLGVNNLPYNWKNF
YPAYYNTDHPLSMNVSGVPHSVFIASAPQQLCTMERTNDLTALLSCIGNASKFVYVSVMN
FIPIIYSKAGNILFWPYIEDELRRTAIDRKVSVKLLISCWQRSSFIMRNFLRSIAMLKSK
NIDIEVKLFIVPDTDPPIPYSRVNHAKYMVTDKTAYIGTSNWTGNYFTDTCGTSINITPD
DGLGLRQQLEDIFMRDWNSKYSYELYDTSPTKRCRLLKNMKQCTNDIYSDEIQPEKEIPE
YSLE
>CUI02274 |CPXV045 protein[Cowpox virus]
MSANCMFNLDNDYIYCKYWKPITYPKALVFISHGAGEHSGRYDELAENISSLGILVFSHD
HIGHGRSNGEKMMIDDFGTYVRDVVQHVVTIKSTYPGVPVFLLGHSMGATISILAAYENP
NLFTAMILMSPLVNAEAVPRLNLLAAKLMGAITPNAPVGKLCPESVSRDMDEVYKYQYDP
LVNHEKIKAGFASQVLKATNKVRKIIPKINTPSLILQGTNNEISDVSGAYYFMQHANCNR
EIKIYEGAKHHLHKETDEVKKSVMKEIETWIFNRVK
>CUI02276 |hypothetical protein pCPXV0240[Cowpox virus]
MDFCKIDVVVSFAHSLDNLINFINTIVPYSSIIELHQFLVESSTTGNIFVKHYNMISPRD
IFIY
```

where

`CUI02270 ; CUI02272 ; CUI02271 ; CUI022799` have been deleted because there where present in both `file 1 and 2`.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with FASTA files and you can handle them easily with awk:

```
$ awk '(NR==FNR){list[$1];next}
       /^>/{key=$0;sub(/^> */,"",key);sub(/ *[|].*$/,"",key);f=1}
       (key in list) {f=0}
       f' file1 file2
```

This works in the following way:

1. **`(NR==FNR){list[$1];next}`:** if we read the first file (`NR==FNR`) store the entry in `list` and move to the next record
2. **`/^>/{key=$0;sub(/^> */,"",key);sub(/ *[|].*$/,"",key);f=1}`:** If we encounter a sequence name, extract the key which is located between `>` and the first `|`. Remove all the irrelevant parts with `sub` and initialze the flag `f` to `1`. This flag indicates if we are going to print the sequence or not.
3. Check if the sequence with key `key` is in `list`. If so, set the flag `f` to `0` as we do not want to print.
4. **`f`:** This will print the line if `f==1`.